# Syntax Error when I try to access model data with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Bit of a newbie to MVC, when I try to access my username property of my viewmodel, I get a syntax error.

```
 @section scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
               var userName = @Model.UserName;
        </script>
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: actually Visual Studio *thinks* there is syntax error but there's not! You've got some solutions:

- put "", like `var userName = "@Model.UserName"`
- ignore the error. Your view will compile because it is not a *real* one
- maybe through a function